# Upgrading RAM to 8 GB – use 2×2 GB or 4 GB?

Tags: memory, upgrade, ddr3

I have a motherboard with four RAM slots. I already installed 4 GB (2×2GB, 1333) of the same RAM type (dual channel) and I want to upgrade RAM to 8 GB – so what is the better option to upgrade to?

- one stick of 4 GB 1333 MHz memory
- two sticks of 2×2 GB 1333 MHz

Note that if I upgrade using the second option, the four sticks will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Get the two additional sticks so your channels are even.
[Dual channel memory configuration](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-the-Dual-Triple-and-Quad-Channel-Memory-Architectures/133/4) requires an even number of chips, with each pair of chips operating at the same frequency with the same capacity.

by installing a single 4GB chip, one of the channels will not be a matched pair, and all three chips will run on the same single channel, and loose the benefits of dual channel architecture.

The Op could install two 4GB chips (12GB total) putting the 2GB pair on one channel and the 4GB pair on the other, but they don't list that as an option.

Comment: see edits per request.